# Does TLS 1.3 include the auth tag from GCM in the record?

Tags: tls, authentication, openssl

When TLS 1.3 is used with GCM AES (128), does the GCM auth tag (calculated right at the end) get  included within the record?

I am looking at the 1.3 RFC and section 5.2 doesn't seem to explicitly mention the GCM auth tag being included anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rfc8446 uses the AEAD 'API' in rfc5116 which **treats the tag as part of the ciphertext**; for AES-GCM ciphersuites see [5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5116#section-5.1) "ciphertext is formed by appending the authentication tag ... to the ciphertext [output by the AES-GCM operation defined in SP800-38D]". Although it doesn't say so, this is reversed on decryption: the 'ciphertext' in the TLS record is split into the 'real' ciphertext and the tag for input to SP800-38D decryption.

Related but a bit obscure, rfc8446 5.2 (at the bottom of page 81) says "length of the AEAD output will generally be larger than the plaintext [which already had inner type and padding added] but by an amount that varies with the AEAD algorithm" -- that variable amount *is* the tag size, which depends on the AEAD algorithm specified by the ciphersuite.